# Do Carmo <Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces> Exercise 1.6.2 (b)

Tags: differential-geometry

This is Do Carmo Excerise 1.6.2(b) in

Given regular smooth curve parametrized by arc length
$$\alpha : I \to R^3 $$
show that the limit shape of circumcircle of triangle formed by $\alpha (s), \alpha (s+h_1), \alpha (s+h_2) $ when $h_1, h_2$ tend to zero is the osculating circle of the curve at $s$.

the previous problem 1.6.2(a) is a problem which requires to show the the limit plane of the plane formed by the three points  $\alpha (s), \alpha (s+h_1), \alpha (s+h_2) $ when $ h_1, h_2$ tend to zero is the osculating plane of the curve at $s$.

Do Carmo provides solution to 1.6.2(a) but does not for 1.6.2(b). It is a chapter regarding local canonical form so it seems local canonical form might help. I can verify the problems' result with quite crude approximation, but have no idea on how to prove rigorously with solid analytic argument. I will appreciate any help a lot.

Comment: It's easy to figure out from the subject matter which book this must be, but in general it's a good idea to give the title of the book as well as the author. Do Carmo wrote two popular books about differential geometry.

Comment: Oh.. I see. Thanks.